# Ruby custom method chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way of chaining multiple custom methods together? I want to put the output of my method directly into the next method in an elegant way. The first one below is what I have now.

```
verified = search_verified(@providers)
matching = search_matching(verified)
deactivated = search_deactivated(matching)
networks = search_networks(deactivated)
designations = search_designations(networks)
disorders = search_disorders(designations)
age_groups = search_age_groups(disorders)
governing = search_governing(age_groups)
search_availabilities(governing)
```

maybe something more along the lines of:

```
search_verified(@providers) 
>> search_matching
>> search_deactivated
>> search_networks 
>> ....
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use [`then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-then) to chain your methods and [numbers parameter](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Numbered+parameters) to simplify the blocks:

```
search_verified(@providers)
  .then { search_matching(_1) }
  .then { search_deactivated(_1) }
  .then { search_networks(_1) }
  .then { search_designations(_1) }
  .then { search_disorders(_1) }
  .then { search_age_groups(_1) }
  .then { search_governing(_1) }
  .then { search_availabilities(_1) }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something along those lines. Ruby 2.6.0 introduces [`then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#method-i-then), and the function composition operators [`<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Method.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [`>>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Method.html#method-i-3E-3E).

You do have to select your methods with [`method(:method_name)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Object.html#method-i-method) because `method_name` by itself invokes the method and does not return it.

```rb
@providers.then(&
  method(:search_verified)     >>
  method(:search_matching)     >>
  method(:search_deactivated)  >>
  method(:search_networks)     >>
  method(:search_designations) >>
  method(:search_disorders)    >>
  method(:search_age_groups)   >>
  method(:search_governing)    >>
  method(:search_availabilities)
)
```

---

If you don't like the character "overhead". You could shrink the amount of characters by storing the [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Object.html#method-i-method) method in a shorter variable first:

```rb
fn = method(:method)

@providers.then(&
  fn[:search_verified] >>
  # ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write that as follows.

```
METHODS = [:verified, :matching, :deactivated, :networks, :designations,
           :disorders, :age_groups, :governing, :search_availabilities]
```

```
def doit(first_arg)
  METHODS.reduce(first_arg) { |arg, meth| send(meth, arg) } 
end
```

This would be called

```
doit(@providers)
```

---

For example:

```
def a(arg)
  arg * 2
end
```

```
def b(arg)
  arg + 1
end
```

```
def c(arg)
  arg/5.0
end
```

```
METHODS = [:a, :b, :c]
```

```
doit(3)
  #=> 1.4
```

---

One could alternatively write

```
def doit(first_arg)
  METHODS.reduce(first_arg) { |arg, meth| method(meth).call(arg) } 
end
```

```
doit(3)
  #=> 1.4
```

One advantage of this approach is that if methods are added, removed or renamed is is only necessary to change the constant `METHODS`; the method `doit` is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

I've not actually tried this other than a quick attempt in the console, but from looking at: https://andersmurphy.com/2019/12/07/ruby-functional-programming.html it looks like something like the following should be possible:

```
pipe = -> *fns {fns.reverse.reduce {|f, g| -> x {f.(g.(x))}}}
add_one = -> x {x + 1}
times_two = -> x {x * 2}

add_one_and_times_two = pipe.(add_one, times_two)

add_one_and_times_two.(2)
=> 6

pipe.(add_one, times_two).(3)
=> 8
```

If you want to use this with methods you can possibly (this seems to work in the console) do something like:

```
def divide_by_three(x); x / 3.0 end

pipe.(
  add_one,
  times_two,
  method(:divide_by_three)
).(4)
=> 3.3333333333333335
```

using the method function as shown in @3limin4t0r's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all the methods are in one class you can chain these methods by returning self in each method.
For the sake of clarity I take your example but the providers are just numbers.

```
class MyClass

  def initialize
    @@providers = [2, 6, 4, 8, 7]
  end
  
  def search_matching 
    # do stuff
    @@providers.select!{ |n| n > 3 }
    self
  end

  def search_deactivated
    # do other stuff
    @@providers.select!{ |n| n < 8 }
    self
  end

  def providers
    @@providers
  end
end

MyClass.new.search_matching.search_deactivated.providers # [6, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score -2):

it depends on what data do you really need and how you define the architecture of your code, i usually make a [Service object](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial).

if you only want to return only the last method output. `return search_availabilities(governing)`.

If you need all variables, you can make it return an array with all the variables or the ones that you need. `return [verified, matching, deactivated, ...]`.